# Rotating textureRegion based on box2D body angle (without sprite)

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, box2d, spritebatch

I am trying to rotate a textureRegion, based on box2d body angle, using the spriteBatcher draw method:

```
SpriteBatch.draw(TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height,float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation)
```

However the resulting rotation looks like this

[image]
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, have tried a lot of different combinations of originX, originY and it is always broken. Tried to setting the origins to center of body, left bottom corner, and no luck.

Looked at the documentation, analzyed the SpriteBatch.class but its unclear to me what's the reason.

How to rotate the texture properly?

EDIT: I cannot use Sprite class, because the textureRegion that is being drawn is an animation frame and afaik you can't make animation frames out of Sprite class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set polygonshape of box2d body like this

```
float width=x,height=y;

PolygonShape polygonShape=new PolygonShape();
polygonShape.setAsBox(width/2, height/2,new Vector2(width/2,height/2),0);
```

setAsBox method of PolygonShape is overloaded.

Comment: I am using this method already, like this:
  shape.setAsBox((animation.getWidth() - animation.getHorizontalOffset()) / 200f,
    (animation.getHeight() - animation.getBottomOffset()) / 200f,new Vector2((animation.getWidth()-animation.getHorizontalOffset())/200f,(animation.getHeight()-animation.getBottomOffset())/200f),0);

but adding the 2 parameters you mentioned makes the box spin crazily

Comment: first of all make simple calculation, so remove offset and check result.

Comment: offset should be multiplied by 2

Comment: multiplying the offset  by 2 worked, I've spent so much time on this, wow. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The origin is in bottom left corner of the image, put it in the center of the image. So make originX width/2 and originY height/2.

Comment: tried that now, its still rotating like in the picture I attached

Comment: are you converting to degrees? body.getAngle() returns the rotation in radians, but you need it on degrees for SpriteBatch.draw

Comment: I'm using this as the rotation parameter: (float) Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle())

Comment: the rotation degree is alright, its just that the image rotated is far from the original coordinates, and as the degree increases its gets even further away

Comment: maybe one of the offsets is negative?, both should be positive values (so its in the center)